# Using relative vs absolute URL for STATIC_URL in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to setup appropriate STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT values for a new Django project, and I'm running into a problem with using an absolute URL for STATIC_URL.

My project is structured like:

```
<project root>
    static
    media
    src
        <apps>
        static
            js
            css
                custom.css
            i
        settings.py
```

In my settings.py, I have

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '../static/'))
```

If I set `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`, then I can access `http://localhost:8000/static/css/custom.css` perfectly.

However, if I use an absolute URL like `STATIC_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/static/'`, as though I were using a CDN, then `http://localhost:8000/static/css/custom.css` returns a 404 error.

Shouldn't these settings be effectively identical? The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url) state STATIC_URL can be absolute. Why does the later setting fail to load static media?

Answer (score 6):

I just tested the same thing, using `http://localhost:8000/static/` doesn't work for me either.

In my settings I keep a development variable, so on localhost the url is '/static/' and when I'm deployed (and I set `DEVELOPMENT = False`), its a full url.

```
if DEVELOPMENT == True:
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
else:
    STATIC_URL = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/static/'
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar, but I switched based on the process' username so I didn't have to worry about setting a variable.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are using the `static` function from the `django.conf.urls.static` to serve your static files in the development environment (that means `DEBUG=True`). Now as you can read in the documentation this function is not working with the absolute urls with `DEBUG` enabled.

So from the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

"This helper function works only in debug mode and only if the given prefix is local (e.g. /static/) and not a URL (e.g. http://static.example.com/)."

Answer (score 1):

The cause and solution was simple, but discovering it was unintuitive based on how I described the problem. I failed to mention that my absolute `STATIC_URL` actually had a different domain (`http://localmedia:8000/static/` not `http://localhost:8000/static/`).

I was doing this as part of a hack to simplify media hosting among several external development Windows machines I was using to test various versions of IE.

However, when there's a mismatch between the domain in `STATIC_URL` and `runserver's` local domain, Django only serves content from STATIC_ROOT and doesn't attempt to retrieve media from app folders. Not sure why, but that's the way it is.

If I ran `manage.py collectstatic`, it would effectively fix the 404 error by copying all app folder media into my STATIC_ROOT. Alternatively, I could just use the same domain in my `STATIC_URL`, and Django would automatically find any uncollected media in the app folders.